# Day360 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datediff

I want to use the `Days360` function in VB.Net. I need to know the difference in days between two dates assuming 360 days in a year (not 365 days the `DateDiff` function uses).

For example `DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,"16/10/2015", "04/02/2016")` = 111 days, but `Days360` should return 109 days.

Comment: which 5 (or 6) days have you omitted from your calendar?

Comment: what I want is that always take the months of 30 days, at the time of calculating the difference, as it does excel day360 formula

Comment: It appears that the logic is described in the documentation for the [DAYS360 function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DAYS360-function-B9A509FD-49EF-407E-94DF-0CBDA5718C2A).  Have you tried to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Days360 function in Excel calculates the days between two dates using a fictional calendar that has 30 days in each month. This method is used for some financial purposes.

You can write a function to do the same calculation.

**[Edit]**
Excel supports two versions of the calculation: one common in the US (this is the default) and the other common in Europe (see the [documentation of the DAYS360 function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/days360-function-b9a509fd-49ef-407e-94df-0cbda5718c2a) for details).

The code I originally posted implemented the European version. I have updated it to support both versions.  Thanks to Nikhil Vartak for pointing this out.

```
Function Days360(startDate As DateTime, endDate As DateTime, euMethod As Boolean) As Integer
    Dim months As Integer = (endDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12 + endDate.Month - startDate.Month

    If euMethod Then
        'Use European method (start or end dates after the 30th of the month are changed to 30th)
        Return months * 30 + Math.Min(30, endDate.Day) - Math.Min(30, startDate.Day)

    Else 'Use US method
        'If the start date is the last day of the month, change it to the 30th
        Dim startDay As Integer = startDate.Day
        startDay = If(startDate.Day >= DateTime.DaysInMonth(startDate.Year, startDate.Month), 30, startDate.Day)

        'If end date is last of the month, change it to the 30th
        Dim endDay As Integer = endDate.Day
        endDay = If(endDate.Day >= DateTime.DaysInMonth(endDate.Year, endDate.Month), 30, endDate.Day)

        'If end date is last of the month and start date is before 30th, change end date to 1st of the next month
        If endDate.Day >= DateTime.DaysInMonth(endDate.Year, endDate.Month) And startDay < 30 Then
            endDay = 1
            months += 1
        End If

        Return months * 30 + endDay - startday
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Start date = 1/15/2017, end date = 3/31/2017 gives 75 but excel gives 76.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Excel supports [two methods for handing dates near the end of the month](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/days360-function-b9a509fd-49ef-407e-94df-0cbda5718c2a). The default is the US method, but the one my answer supports is the European method. If I only support one method, I should have supported the default one. I'll edit the answer to support both methods.